# Flutter List<Dynamic> should be List<DataRow>

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm trying to use flutter's DataTable widget but I keep getting this error, I want to create a method to generate the data for the table.

```
var dataList = [
    DataSectionCollection(
      category: 'Category',
      date: 'January 01, 2019',
      item: [
        DataSectionItem(
            symbol: "ICMS", amount: " 474.858.228.17", percentage: 3.55),
        DataSectionItem(
            symbol: "ICMS", amount: " 474.858.228.17", percentage: 3.55),
        DataSectionItem(
            symbol: "ICMS", amount: " 474.858.228.17", percentage: 3.55),
        DataSectionItem(
            symbol: "ICMS", amount: " 474.858.228.17", percentage: 3.55),
      ],
    ),
    DataSectionCollection(
      category: 'Category',
      date: 'January 01, 2019',
      item: [
        DataSectionItem(
            symbol: "AAAA", amount: " 474.858.228.17", percentage: 3.55),
        DataSectionItem(
            symbol: "AAA", amount: " 474.858.228.17", percentage: 3.55),
        DataSectionItem(
            symbol: "AAA", amount: " 474.858.228.17", percentage: 3.55),
        DataSectionItem(
            symbol: "AAA", amount: " 474.858.228.17", percentage: 3.55),
      ],
    ),
    DataSectionCollection(
      category: 'Category',
      date: 'January 01, 2019',
      item: [
        DataSectionItem(
            symbol: "BBBB", amount: " 474.858.228.17", percentage: 3.55),
        DataSectionItem(
            symbol: "BBBB", amount: " 474.858.228.17", percentage: 3.55),
        DataSectionItem(
            symbol: "BBBB", amount: " 474.858.228.17", percentage: 3.55),
        DataSectionItem(
            symbol: "BBBB", amount: " 474.858.228.17", percentage: 3.55),
      ],
    ),
  ];

  _getData01(List listOfData) {
    return DataTable(
      columns: listOfData
          .map(
            (column) => DataColumn(
              label: Container(),
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
      rows: listOfData
          .map((stat) => stat.item.map((row) => DataRow(cells: [
                DataCell(
                  Text(row.symbol),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Text(row.amount),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Text("${row.symbol}"),
                ),
              ])))
          .toList(),
    );
  }
```

I'm not entirely sure what i'm doing wrong. Can someone help please? The first bit where i map over the list to create the columns work fine by the second didn't.

Comment: Could you please show how `DataSectionCollection` implementation?

Comment: class DataSectionCollection {
  final String category;
  final String date;
  final List item;

  DataSectionCollection({this.category, this.date, this.item});
}

class DataSectionItem {
  final String symbol;
  final String amount;
  final double percentage;

  DataSectionItem({this.symbol, this.amount, this.percentage});
}

Comment: just change the `final List item` in the `DataSectionCollection` into `final List<DataSectionItem> item`

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: In the `_getData01(List listOfData)` change to `_getData01(List<DataSectionCollection> listOfData)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is in the nesting of the `.map()` method when going through your data. I untangled it to make it more readable and swapped to `.forEach()` methods:

```
Widget _getData01(List listOfData) {
  List<DataRow> rows = [];

  listOfData.forEach((stat){
    stat.item.forEach((row){
      rows.add(
        DataRow(
          cells: [
            DataCell(
              Text(row.symbol),
            ),
            DataCell(
              Text(row.amount),
            ),
            DataCell(
              Text("${row.symbol}"),
            ),
          ]
        )
      );
    });
  });

  return DataTable(
    columns: listOfData.map(
      (column) => DataColumn(
        label: Container(),
      )
    ).toList(),
    rows: rows,
  );
}
```

I could only test this by replacing your model classes with my own data, so please test it and give me feedback.

Comment: Okay, i understand, thank you very much and yes it worked.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Good luck with your app!

Comment: @VenkataKrishnanS You're welcome! Good luck with your app! If it fixed your issue, consider upvoting the anwer.

Comment: one request, for the column part, it will be good to give an explicit example. I had to hard code the column label part, did not know how to get the column automatically from the json/ list...

Comment: The response was for the OP's specific question. What were you looking for?