# How to retrieve data from List<Map<String, dynamic>> model in DataTable flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, model, nested

let's say I have a model like this ...

```
class UserModel {
  UserModel({
    required this.data1,
    required this.data2,
    required this.sessions,
  });

  String data1;
  String data2;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> sessions;
}
```

and I have variable data like this ...

```
var userData = [
  UserModel(
    data1: 'Jhon Doe',
    data2: 'Research',
    sessions: [
      {"date": "20 june", "status": "good", "durations": 13},
      {"date": "22 june", "status": "good", "durations": 33},
      {"date": "23 june", "status": "excellent", "durations": 23},
      {"date": "25 june", "status": "good", "durations": 60}
    ],
  ),
  UserModel(
    data1: 'Jean Doe',
    data2: 'Research',
    sessions: [
      {"date": "20 june", "status": "good", "durations": 13},
      {"date": "22 june", "status": "excellent", "durations": 33},
      {"date": "23 june", "status": "excellent", "durations": 23},
      {"date": "25 june", "status": "good", "durations": 60}
    ],
  ),
  UserModel(
    data1: 'Mark Doe',
    data2: 'Resource',
    sessions: [
      {"date": "20 june", "status": "low", "durations": 30},
      {"date": "22 june", "status": "good", "durations": 13},
      {"date": "23 june", "status": "excellent", "durations": 23},
      {"date": "25 june", "status": "good", "durations": 60}
    ],
  ),
];
```

so, How do I retrieve only all "status" in Map of every User?

I hope you can share the answers, Thanks... cheers

**UPDATE!**

I tried to implement it in **Datatable Flutter** this is my full code...

```
class DetailPage extends StatefulWidget {

  //selected user variable
  final UserModel element;

  const DetailPage({Key? key, required this.element}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DetailPage> createState() => _DetailPageState();
}

class _DetailPageState extends State<DetailPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(...),
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        return ListView(
          children: [
            _createDataTable(),
          ],
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}

DataTable _createDataTable() {
  return DataTable(columns: _createColumns(), rows: _createRows());
}

List<DataColumn> _createColumns() {
  return [
    const DataColumn(label: Text('Date')),
    const DataColumn(label: Text('Status')),
    const DataColumn(label: Text('Durations')),
  ];
}

List<DataRow> _createRows() {
  return [
    for (var element in userData) {
      for (var elementSession in element.sessions) {
        DataRow(cells: [
          DataCell(Text(elementSession['date'])),
          DataCell(Text(elementSession['status'])),
          DataCell(Text(elementSession['durations'])),
        ]);
      }
    })
  ];
}
```

The problem is, The argument type 'List.dynamic.' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List.DataRow.'.

Comment: what is the exact result you require. can you put a sample of the result you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the previous answer so I can figure out the logic and solve the problem by reversing the code, I got the answer to a similar question from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59778238/17031433).

hire my working full code :

```
class DetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  //selected user constructor
  final UserModel? elementUser;

  const DetailPage({Key? key, this.elementUser}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DetailPage> createState() => _DetailPageState();
}

class _DetailPageState extends State<DetailPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(...),
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        return ListView(
          children: [
            //widget dataTable tag
            _createDataTable(widget.elementUser),
          ],
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}

_createDataTable(UserModel? elementUser) {
  //List<DataRow> 
  List<DataRow> rows = [];
  
  //generate selected user nested data
  for (var row in elementUser!.sessions) {
    rows.add(
      DataRow(
        cells: [
          DataCell(
            Text(row['date']),
          ),
          DataCell(
            Text(row['status']),
          ),
          DataCell(
            Text(row['durations'].toString()),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  
  //create dataTable
  return DataTable(
    columns: _createColumns(),
    rows: rows,
  );
}

//List<DataColumn>
List<DataColumn> _createColumns() {
  return [
    const DataColumn(label: Text('Date')),
    const DataColumn(label: Text('Status')),
    const DataColumn(label: Text('Durations')),
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for each loop

```
userData.forEach((element){
  element.sessions.forEach(sessionElement){
    print(sessionElement['status']);
  }
});
```

You can use the same logic in for loop too.

Comment: Thanks, I got the idea to get data from the list (List.Map) but the DataRow flutter has its own list type (List.DataRow). I added the full code in the question section for more detail, maybe you have solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forEach` function to iterate through the list

```
userData.forEach((e){
  e.sessions.forEach(sessionElement){
    print(sessionElement['date']);
    print(sessionElement['status']);
    print(sessionElement['duration']);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the idea to get data from the list (List.Map) but the DataRow flutter has its own list type (List.DataRow). I added the full code in the question section for more detail, maybe you have the solution.

Comment: Can you let us know , where the error is occured

Comment: at `List<DataRow> _createRows() {...}` section. the result of looping it will come out as `List<Map>` or `List<dynamic>` but the flutter data table row has its own type of list `List<DataRow>`. in that means it will don't match with each other list type and causing an error.